# where is dispatch coming from in this line? export const setAlert = (msg, alertType,timeout=5000) =>dispatch =>

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I came across this code. He/she Is creating an action for redux in react-redux app. I don't understand where dispatch is coming from . Can you explain please also is this a good practice?

`import uuid from 'uuid';
import {SET_ALERT,REMOVE_ALERT} from './types';
export const setAlert = (msg, alertType,timeout=5000) =>dispatch =>{
    const id = uuid.v4();
    dispatch ({
        type:SET_ALERT,
        payload:{msg,
            alertType,
            id}
    }); 

    setTimeout(()=>dispatch({type:REMOVE_ALERT,payload:id}),timeout)}`

Comment: You are exporting a function `setAlert` (with arguments `msg`, `alertType`, `timeout`) which returns another (unnamed) function (with argument `dispatch`). It appears that whatever is importing your module is supposed to call `setAlert` once to get a curried function with the set `msg`, `alertType` and `msg` and can then call the returned second function and pass a callback. That callback is what you'll get as `dispatch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is using redux-thunk, which works as a middleware. setAlert returns the function, which is being called with the dispatch as first parameter of that function. It maybe helps more to understand if you clean it up a bit

```
export const setAlert = (msg, alertType,timeout=5000) => {
    const id = uuid.v4();

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch ({
            type:SET_ALERT,
            payload:{
                msg,
                alertType,
                id
            }
        }); 
    };
```

I generally use it in cases I need to work with async functions inside an action, such as ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is coming from `mapDispatchToProps`:

```js
// action
export const action = (params) => async (dispatch) => // it can be async btw
  actionCodeHere()

// component
import {action as importedAction} from 'action'

const component = ({action}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => { action(params) }, [])

  return <div/>
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  action: importedAction
} // just object

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(component)
```

Is it good practice?

I think it's better than many other ways I saw (redux saga especially, senseless and merciless), this has less code than when mapDispatchToProps is a function.

Easier is only to import `dispatch` from store directly in actions file and not using `mapDispatchToProps` at all, but I never saw this approach, seems like it is not good practice.

Comment: thanks. i understand now. when we give action to connect function it pass dispatch to it.